# How does the OverlapCircle Work in Unity?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Below is the Code I read somewhere to keep a check on whether the player is on the Ground or Not.

We have to set the `LayerMask whatIsGround` from the Inspector.

I know the `OverlapCircle` method creates some kind of Circle but i don't know what exactly doest it do and what does it check.

How does it use the `LayerMask` to determine whether it's on ground or not.

```
    public LayerMask whatIsground;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public bool isGrounded;

isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position,groundCheckRaadius,whatIsground);
```

Comment: layermask is a bitmask. the easiest way to set it up is to expose it to the inspector by creating a public field (well at least as long as bitshifting doesnt tell you anything). its used to mask certain layers to be used for collision detection (or also culling or lightning, depending on what you use it with). the documentation should help you further.

Comment: Here are some links that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-J5sCRipA0 / http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html / http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/757716/physics2d-overlapcircle.html

Comment: Thanks mate I'll watch them